# Automatic Scrolling as it receives the objects

Tags: c#, ngui

I have some pop up buttons on my scrollview. When hit play ,buttons pop up and if done manually scrolling is also supported. But what I am trying to bring is when my scene loads both my buttons and scrollview should work simultaneously i.e buttons popping up and scrollview getting scrolled as it receives the buttons. Any help would be appreciated. And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right u need to scroll automatically each time an item is added to your scrollview.

U could put this in button click event handler:

```
scrollViewer.LineDown();
```

scrollViewer is in this case scrollviewer object it's self.

If you're using MVVM pattern, I suggest u to create a behavior class and put it there or via command attached to the button. The solution with command is easier, but dirty.